# Asterisk AMI incoming calls returns no calls

Tags: python, asterisk

I have the following function with the aim is to get incoming calls from my Python web interface from the Asterisk server.

```
def fetch_events(event, manager):

with app.app_context():

    if event.name == 'CoreShowChannel':
        id = event.message['accountcode']
        data = {
                'user_id': id,
                'caller_id': event.message['CallerIDnum'],
                'channel': event.message['Channel'],
                'duration': event.message['Duration'],
                'context': event.message['Context'],
                'extension': event.message['Extension'],
                'line': event.message['ConnectedLineNum'],
                #'channel_state': event.message['ChannelState'],
                'channel_state': event.message['ChannelStateDesc'],
                }
        user = System().getUserById(id)
        if user:
            profile = {
                        'firstname': user['firstname'],
                        'lastname': user['lastname']
                        'email': user['email']
                    }

        else:
            profile = {
                        'first_name': "No firstname",
                        'last_name': "No lastname"
                    }
        data.update(profile)   
        g.channels.append(data)
    if event.name == 'CoreShowChannelsComplete':
        g.complete = True

    if not event.name:
        data = {
            "connectivity":"Not connected",
            "event-name":"No event name"
        }
        g.channels.append(data)
        g.complete = True


    @app.route('/incoming-calls')
    def incoming_calls():
   /**** I have already login and connect *****/
   g.channels = []
   g.complete = False
    manager.register_event('*', fetch_events)
    res = manager.send_action({'Action':'CoreShowChannels'})

    try:

        while not g.complete:

            time.sleep(0.5)
        manager.close()
        return json.dumps(g.channels)
```

But when I try getting incoming calls events after registering the handle_event method I get an empty array. It seems there is something wrong with the handle_event method but I can't get to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use (listen) 'Newexten' event and extract 'context' from that event ,and then look up if the calls come from incoming context if it true ,then use other variables from that event. Don't use action 'CoreShowChannel' because it will list current active channels.

Comment: Please Milorad, can you explain it better to me in code. I still do not get you.

Comment: And even the CoreShowChannel I am currently using does not show any active calls.

Comment: Am I to check for the event name like this -> if event.name == 'Newexten' , register and send action like this ->  manager.register_event('*', handle_event)
        res = manager.send_action({'Action':'Newevent'})

Answer (score 0):

When someone call the Asterisk for example incoming call to trunk num ,Asterisk fired 'Newexten' event. The data structure of that event is:

```
`{ event: 'Newexten',
   privilege: 'call,all',
   channel: 'SIP/NameOfyourSIPprovider-0000ae7d',//channel that will be bridged
   channelstate: '0',
   channelstatedesc: 'Down',//the channel is currently down because no one is answered
   calleridnum: '060444333',// num of calling party
   calleridname: '<unknown>',
   connectedlinenum: '+34312345678',//your trunk num
   connectedlinename: '<unknown>',
   language: 'en',
   accountcode: '',
   context: 'from-trunk',//context(extensions.conf) for incoming calls
   exten: '060444333',//num of calling party
   priority: '1',
   uniqueid: '1471265139.357602',//unique id of channel
   linkedid: '1471265138.357596',//linked id of channel that will be bridged
   extension: '060444333',//num of calling party
   application: 'AppDial',
   appdata: '(Outgoing Line)' }`
```

Comment: Oladapo you must read this document https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AMI+v2+Specification to understand call flow and AMI protocol. I personally use Node.js for manipulating  AMI. I'm not familiar with python and AMI interface.

Comment: Milorad, When I made the calls, it is not yet in production mode and I get an IVR, do you think that might be the cause. Because even when I am using CoreShowChannel, I get no active calls object

Comment: My problem is this, what event do I register and send action to, if you look at my source code on github https://github.com/Pinsonbavard/myproject/blob/master/asterisk/ami. I know I am to register which I register (*) to mean all and send action

Comment: Now the Asterisk AMI has been working and suddenly it stops working yesterday. I don't know what went wrong but I noticed it is taking a lot of time to connect and eventually gives a 502 bad gateway